# Why TypeScript complains about parent class inheritance?

Tags: javascript, typescript

So, I have this code base:

```
var MicroEvent  = function(){}
MicroEvent.prototype    = {
    bind    : function(event, fct){
        this._events = this._events || {};
        this._events[event] = this._events[event]   || [];
        this._events[event].push(fct);
    },
    unbind  : function(event, fct){
        this._events = this._events || {};
        if( event in this._events === false  )  return;
        this._events[event].splice(this._events[event].indexOf(fct), 1);
    },
    trigger : function(event /* , args... */){
        this._events = this._events || {};
        if( event in this._events === false  )  return;
        for(var i = 0; i < this._events[event].length; i++){
            this._events[event][i].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1))
        }
    }
};

class PluginManager extends MicroEvent {
     registerPlugin(pluginName: string, applicationName: string, active: boolean = true) {
          // code
     }
     // ...code
}
```

Using this code I am keep getting this error:
[image: error image]

I was trying to add .d.ts file as this:

```
declare interface MicroEvent {
    registerPlugin(arg1: string, arg2: string, arg3?: boolean): void;
    bind(event: string, fct: string):void
    unbind(event: string, fct: string):void
    trigger(event: string):void
}
```

But it does not fix an error.

What causes this error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should `declare class MicroEvent` instead of `declare interface MicroEvent`.   Else you will need to do `declare const MicroEvent: () => MicroEvent`.

Comment: @jcalz okay, I have changed my .d.ts but issue persists. Both .ts and .d.ts. file in the same directory. I should not import .d.ts. file in .ts, should I?

Comment: Using the code you posted you get `Type '() => void' is not a constructor function type.`

Comment: You should *either* put the existing `MicroEvent` code in a separate place (it seems like pure JS and not TS so it should be possible to do this) and refer to its types with the `declare` code above, *or* you need to properly annotate the `MicroEvent` code.  The latter is what @mbojko's answer is telling you to do.

Comment: @jcalz actually `MicroEvent` event code exists in `node_modules` folder, so it is in separate file. So what will be the final code? Still does not work :(

Right now I am using `declare class` as you suggested and `MicroEvent` in the separate file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mixing conventions (prototype and class) seems like asking for trouble (and the source of confusion for TypeScript, likely). Just stick to one pattern:

```
class MicroEvent {
    bind //...
    unbind  //...
    trigger //...
};

class PluginManager extends MicroEvent { //...
```

Comment: Yep, I know, thanks, but it is no opportunity now to do that

Comment: @NikitaShchypyplov Why not?

Comment: It is in node_modules.

Comment: Ofc I can place in my own codebase, but I think it is not the way it should work, isn't it?